# org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting:

> org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403

in the following code.

```
try {
     String url = "https://pixabay.com/ko/videos/";
     Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://pixabay.com/ko/videos/")
             .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36")
             .get();
     Elements data = doc.select("div.item");
     int size = data.size();             
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
         String videoUrl = data.select("div.media")
                 .eq(i)
                 .attr("data-mp4");
         videoUrl = "https:" + videoUrl;

         String previewUrl = data.select("div.media")
                 .select("img")
                 .eq(i)
                 .attr("src");
         videoItems.add(new VideoItem(videoUrl, previewUrl));                
      }
```

The error is occurring in the line:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("pixabay.com/ko/videos/") .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36") .get();
```

I think there is a problem with the user agent.

Can anybody help me solve this problem?

Comment: Could you clarify where exactly the exception is thrown ?

Comment: Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://pixabay.com/ko/videos/")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36")
                    .get();     // i think userAgent has problem

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you need to set a referrer and ignorecontent type.
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://pixabay.com/ko/videos/")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) 
                               AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
                               Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .get();